# Integer Programming with Binary Variables.

Tags: optimization, integer-programming, binary-programming

**Question :**
A company wants to form three different teams $A, B, C$ from a pool of 7 employees, which we represent as the set $E=\{1, \ldots, 7\}$. Each employee $i$ has a certain number of years $\alpha_{i}$ of experience at the company, and has $\beta_{i}$ as their current annual salary. Note that $\alpha_{i}, \beta_{i}$ are constants, but you may assume that $0 \leq \alpha_{i} \leq 10$ and $0 \leq \beta_{i} \leq 100000$.
We define binary variables $x_{i j}$ for all $i \in E$ and $j \in\{A, B, C\}$ to represent
$$
x_{i j}=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
1 & \text { employee } i \text { is on team } j \\
0 & \text { otherwise }
\end{array}\right.
$$
Suppose we are writing an integer program, and we have already defined the constraints which ensure that each $x_{i j}$ is a binary variable.

For each of the following conditions, give constraints that correctly formulate it. You may use additional variables. You need to explain why your constrains work.
At least 2 of these 3 conditions hold:

- Team $A$ has at least 5 years of experience.
- Team $B$ has at most 250000 in combined annual salary.
- Teams $B$ and $C$ have the same number of employees.

[Question Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1Gda.png)

---

I am working on this optimization problem and have been stuck trying to define and apply binary variables  to this question.

I understand what the question is asking and can formulate each constraint individually but I do not know how to formulate the linear constraints such that "at least 2 of the 3 conditions are fulfilled".

My thought was to introduce 3 binary variables for the 3 conditions, say y<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>2</sub>, y<sub>3</sub>, and have them take on the value 1 if the condition is satisfied and 0 otherwise. I do not know how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With these three binary variables, impose the constraint $y_1+y_2+y_3\ge 2$, together with (linear) big-M constraints that enforce $$y_k =1\implies \text{condition $k$ is satisfied}.$$
Before attempting the big-M constraints, you should model each condition $k$ on its own with a linear constraint that does not involve $y$. For the first condition,
$$\sum_{i=1}^7 \alpha_i x_{i,A} \ge 5,$$
rewrite as
$$5 - \sum_{i=1}^7 \alpha_i x_{i,A} \le 0,$$
and then the corresponding big-M constraint is
$$5 - \sum_{i=1}^7 \alpha_i x_{i,A} \le 5(1-y_1),$$
which you could rewrite as
$$\sum_{i=1}^7 \alpha_i x_{i,A} \ge 5 y_1.$$
If $y_1=1$, the constraint enforces the desired condition to be satisfied.  If $y_1=0$, the constraint is redundant.

Here, the value of big-M is $5$.  More generally, the constraint
$$f(x) \le M(1-y),$$
where $M$ is a (small) upper bound on $f(x)$,
enforces the rule:
if $y=1$ then $f(x) \le 0$.

The second condition is similar.  For the third condition, rewrite the equality as two $\le 0$ inequalities and apply big-M to each one separately.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/IZATTiz.jpg                                                             This is what I had for the 3 conditions separately. I tried to involve  the variable y by multiplying it on the right-hand side and editing each expression to satisfy what I need, but wasn't sure exactly how.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thank you for showing me an example. I am working on the second condition right now. This is what I have, $$\sum_{i=1}^7 \beta_i x_{i,B} \le 250000y_2$$ so the big-M value would be 250000. However I see that when $y_2$=0, then the constraint would imply that Team B's combined salary would be negative. Also the other constraint, $$\sum_{i=1}^7 \beta_i x_{i,B} \ge 250000(1-y_2)$$ is not redundant and if $y_2$=0 would not satisfy the question.

Comment: For the second condition, first rewrite as $\le 0$, and then obtain $M$ as a small upper bound on the LHS.

Comment: $$\sum_{i=1}^7 \beta_i x_{i,B} \le 250000$$ $$\sum_{i=1}^7 \beta_i x_{i,B}  - 250000 \le 0$$ $$\sum_{i=1}^7 \beta_i x_{i,B}  - 250000 \le 250000(1-y_2)$$ $$\sum_{i=1}^7 \beta_i x_{i,B} \le 250000(2-y_2)$$                                                  Is this the correct way to approach condition 2? I see that if $y_2$=0 then the constraint is redundant.

Comment: Almost, but $M$ should be $7\cdot 100000-250000$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused on how we are choosing M. For the first condition we only use the value of the question's constraint, but for the second condition we are considering the maximum salary Team B could potentially have. Why don't we choose M in condition 1 to be $7\cdot 10-5$, for example?

Comment: The value of big-M is always an upper bound on the LHS. For the first condition, the $5$ comes from $5-7\cdot 0$.

Comment: Okay, I think I am comfortable with it now. Just to make sure, these are the two constraints I have for condition 3, choosing M to be 6 because the upper bound on the difference between two teams' employees is 7-1: $$\sum_{i=1}^7 \ x_{i,B} \ - \sum_{i=1}^7 \ x_{i,C} \le 6(1-y_3)$$ $$\sum_{i=1}^7 \ x_{i,C} \ - \sum_{i=1}^7 \ x_{i,B} \le 6(1-y_3)$$

Comment: Yes, assuming each team must be nonempty.

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance. This is going to help me a lot later on into the course as well.